# Namespace schema for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I come from the world of Java.  In Java there are packages, for example, "com.mycompany.billing" and classes that are inside the package, for example, "BillProcessor".  The company in which I work is starting a new project and I need to decide on a good namespace schema.  I'm thinking of projecting how it's done in Java to JavaScript, for example, having a namespace "com.mycompany.billing" and a class that's in a file like "BillProcessor.js".  In addition, unit testing is vital so I need such a structure that is easy to unit test.

Can somebody suggest a good approach?

---

I think that I came up with a good solution, please advise.  As an example I'll make a billing page.  There are 4 files:

${root}/billing.html - contains an input box for the name on credit card

${root}/js/com/mycompany/common/common.js - initializes logging and error handling

${root}/js/com/mycompany/common/Url.js - class that is used to perform an AJAX call

${root}/js/com/mycompany/aproject/billing.js - initializes things on the billing page

So for example, common.js contains:

```
var com_mycompany_common_common = function() {

    function log(message) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ': ' + message);
    }

    function init() {
        window.onerror = function(message) {
            log('Unhandled error: ' + message);
        }
    }

    return {
        log: log,
        init: init
    }
 } ();

 $(document).ready(function() {
      try {
           com_mycompany_common_common.init();
      } catch (e) {
           console.log('Error during initialization: ' + e);
      }
});
```

Url.js:

```
function com_mycompany_common_Url(url) {    
    this.url = url;
}

com_mycompany_common_Url.prototype.addParameter(name, value) {
    this.url += '?' + name + '=' + value;
}

com_mycompany_common_Url.prototype.ajax() {
    com_mycompany_common_common.log('Send ajax to: ' + this.url);
}
```

billing.js

```
var com_mycompany_aproject_billing = function() {

    function init() {
        $('#submitButton').click(function() {
            Url url = new com_mycompany_common_Url('http://bla.com/process/billing');
            var creditCardName = $('#ccName').val();
            url.addParameter('name', creditCardName);
            url.ajax();
        }
    }

    return {init: init};
} ();

$(document).ready(function() {
      try {
           com_mycompany_aproject_billing.init();
      } catch (e) {
           console.log('Error during initialization: ' + e);
      }
});
```

billing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Billing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Enter name on credit card: <input type="text" id="ccName" /><br><br>
        <button id="submitButton">Submit Payment</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/com/mycompany/common/common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/com/mycompany/common/Url.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/com/mycompany/aproject/billing.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter9.html seems to go over the topic in depth.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you browse through [FullCalendar's source code](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar)

Comment: @TomIngram I like what I'm seeing.  Do I understand correctly, taking an Object Oriented approach to JavaScript?  Hmm, I see that he's not using an automated unit testing approach which is not good for him I think.

Comment: @SBel object orientation is ummm 'interesting' in js especially comparatively to say java, for example afaik `var foo = function() { }` `foo` is a object and at the same time can serve as a namespace, I believe it's this whole idea of nesting and scope so perhaps bears a small similarity to inner classes in java. you may find [this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript) somewhat interesting. as for a `schema` I think you could use a similar convention for namespace i.e. `var mycomp = {}; mycomp.billing = { /*further nesting of classes*/ }`

Comment: @TomIngram I did not follow everything that you said, take a look at my solution that I edited on top, I think it's good.  It uses a class and not a class.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time people use the Object Literal pattern to achieve name spacing in JavaScript.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg578608

You can "nest" namespaces like so:

```
var MyCompany = MyCompany || {};
MyCompany.Billing = MyCompany.Billing || {};
// etc...
```

Another ScriptJunkie article that covers some namespacing stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh377172.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**I'M POSTING THIS QUESTION ON https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/approach-to-organizing-javascript-for-an-html-page MAYBE I'LL GET ANSWERS THERE.**